# How do I make an HTTP request to Django Rest Framework with Session Authentication?

Tags: python, django, cookies, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to access an API endpoint protected with DRF's [session authentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#sessionauthentication). This requires passing the CSRF cookie in the request headers, which I have done following the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#ajax), like this:

```
import * as Cookies from "js-cookie";
var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');

fetch('/api/myendpoint', { headers: { 'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken }})
  .then(response => ...)
```

I have turned on session authentication in my settings.py like this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}
```

Django login and authentication is working correctly for normal pages, but not for my API calls. I always get a 403 error with the response

> Authentication credentials were not provided.

I have checked that the X-CSRFToken header value is correctly set to the current csrftoken cookie value by looking at the request in Chrome's network panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/349#issuecomment-225699815). The csrftoken is not supposed to be in the request headers for GET. Instead,

```
fetch('/api/workflows', { credentials: 'include' })...
```

which includes cookies, as described in the [Fetch docs](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch).

X-CSRFToken must still be set for PUT, PATCH and DELETE requests